# Ubuntu Crontab not running shell script correctly?

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I want crontab to launch a minecraft server on boot.
I've got cron running a shell script, which runs it in a new terminal window as cron typically runs things in the background(?) Running the cron script in terminal launches the server correctly:

Working Terminal code:

```
cd /home/ryan/minecraft_server && sh PreLaunch.sh
```

cron:

```
@reboot cd /home/ryan/minecraft_server && sh PreLaunch.sh
```

PreLaunch:

```
sudo gnome-terminal -e ./launch.sh
```

Launch:

```
Xmx=-Xmx1024M
Xms=-Xms1024M
Ver=1.8.7
echo -e "---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---\n
Launching Server:\n
Minecraft Verson $Ver\n
    Config:
        $Xmx\n
        $Xms\n
---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---\n"
java $Xmx $Xms -jar /home/ryan/minecraft_server/minecraft_server.1.8.7.jar nogui
```

I've tested my crontab script by adding a second one but it just runs a shell script that makes a new folder which works, so I'm pretty out of ideas.

Comment: You don't need gnome terminal to launch a headless app, just run the launch.sh itself from cron.

Comment: I've gotten it working using this cron script @reboot env DISPLAY=:0.0 gnome-terminal -e ./Launch.sh

It runs the script on boot and has it in a window allowing me to monitor it easily.